# Where can I find the cache properties in the Magento 2 database?

Tags: magento2, database, cache

I've had some troubles with the caches, they are enabling via CLI using **production mode** but it's not showing on my admin panel as enabled, it just works using **developer mode**.

I wondering check the cache state into the database if it's an issue related with third-party modules or my environment.

**Where could I check my cache status into the database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache statuses are not saved into the database.
It is saved inside `app/etc/env.php` with array key **cache_types**.

There you can find its status 0 or 1.

```
'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'translate' => 1
    ],
```